# Many ajax requests or load data one time in browser?

Tags: javascript, javascript-remoting, data

I am interested in the best practice for an autocomplete service I am working on.  Is the best practice to make many ajax requests or to load data one time when the page loads?  The data consists of about 40,000 locations.  With that much data, it would make sense to go with JavaScript remoting and make a lot of ajax requests.  Interested in recommendations and best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Visualforce remoting.

---

It will help your page to load faster as you won't have to query and process those 40,000 records on page load and It will also reduce view state size which is limited to 135KB.

In your VF remote call you can put a condition to fetch the data from DB if the user enter 3 or more characters. Also if you can add a de-bounce logic, It will prevent your server calls. You can add a debounce value of 1 second so that if no key is pressed withing 1 second, a server call is made.

This can be achieved by timeout functionality in java-script or if you are using a JS framework like Angular, it provides that functionality.

---

However there are some components present on Salesforce AppExchange that can be used. You may look into them if they are perfect for you use case. One of them is: [AutoComplete Component for Salesforce](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000004cxZsEAI)

I am not affiliated in any way with this.